# Annoying white space around a full screen canvas in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've searched for a ton of solutions on this issue but I haven't had any luck when it comes to implementation.

Everything is working fine, but there is this annoying white border around the canvas. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var x = window.innerWidth - 20;
var y = window.innerHeight - 20;

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.style.width  = x.toString() + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = y.toString() + 'px';
}

var granimInstance = new Granim({
    element: '#canvas',
    name: 'radial-gradient',
    direction: 'radial',
    opacity: [1, 1],
    isPausedWhenNotInView: true,
    states : {
        "default-state": {
            gradients: [
                ['#ffb347', '#ffcc33'],
                ['#83a4d4', '#b6fbff'],
                ['#9D50BB', '#6E48AA']
            ]
        }
    }
});

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;

resizeCanvas();
```

```css
.canvas {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/granim/1.0.6/granim.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Announcements</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/club_meetingv2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/club_meetingv2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Having found the answer to the problem, you are encouraged to add an answer answering your own question and mark it "accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I've found a solution.

```
body {margin: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've said there's an annoying white border, do you mean in the far right and bottom of the gradient?

If so it's due to the first few lines of code:

`var x = window.innerWidth - 20;`
`var y = window.innerHeight - 20;`

You're taking 20px of width and height out of it from the right and bottom. Removing this as in the codepen below will achieve what I think you want?

https://codepen.io/Robhern135/pen/NwxoMR

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this in the post: the -20 on the width and height got rid of the scrollbars that were forming while making a full screen canvas in Chrome.

Comment: Do you have a live version so I can view it in chrome rather than having to view in codepen etc? As I cannot see the annoying white space you speak of

Comment: I seemed to have solved it.

body {margin: 0;} does the trick

But thanks anyway!